# linux text editor with no prompt autosave and restore?

Tags: linux, notepad++, prompt, autosave

I am looking for some way to take ad hoc notes on linux where I don't need to explicitly save those notes.

On windows, I use *Notepad++* that has a feature where new, untitled documents are **automatically saved** (without prompting the user) and **restored** when the program is opened again.

On linux, however, I have tried *Notepadqq*, which has the same feature, but it's too buggy for work use and doesn't have a lot of support.

Comment: this should be on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried ```vi```?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/).

Both have the feature you requested. They both are very stable and there are many plugins and themes.

Comment: Though these both have the feature, they are slow to load and definitely NOT aimed at quick notes. Notepadqq (and Notepad++) is much quicker, though I don't think the brief note idea is really part of their intended use, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you like notepad++, just use it !

I have v7.5.4 currently running in Wine on a CentOS7.

Your autosave feature is there and works...

(see https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2983 )

Comment: Wine is not an option due to limited disk space and an older computer. I do have the option to switch to windows, but obviously that removes all the rest of the benefits of linux.